# Form not submitting in spring (SimpleController)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am  extending SimpleFormController in my controller and using formBackingObject method to display some data  on form load .But when i hit submit button on my we page the form is not submitting ,it event did not go to 
 OnSubmit method.I don't know what is going wrong ,Please help me.

Thank you

below is my code

Mapping

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="river.amit.com"/> 
    <bean id="viewResolver"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
       <property name="mappings">
        <props>
           <prop key="/hello.html">helloController</prop>
           <prop key="/login.html">loginController</prop>
           <prop key="/role.html">roleController</prop>
           <prop key="/person.html">personController</prop>
          </props>
       </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="helloController" class="river.amit.com.HelloWorldController"/>
    <bean id="loginController" class="river.amit.com.LoginController"/>
    <bean id="roleController" class="river.amit.com.RoleController"/>
    <bean id="personController" class="river.amit.com.PersonController">
    <property name="formView" value="person" />
    <property name="successView" value="message" />
    </bean>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="hl" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver"       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />
        <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
      <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/river"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value=""></property>  
    </bean>  
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>\river\amit\com\curd\login.hbm.xml</value>  
         <value>\river\amit\com\curd\Person.hbm.xml</value> 
        <value>\river\amit\com\curd\Role.hbm.xml</value>
         </list>  
        </property>  
          <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>  
           <tx:annotation-driven/>
      <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

       <bean id="service" class="river.amit.com.service.LoginService"></bean>
       <bean id="logindao" class="river.amit.com.dao.LoginDao"> 
         <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean> 
    <bean id="roleService" class="river.amit.com.service.RoleService"></bean>
      <bean id="roleDao" class="river.amit.com.dao.RoleDao">    
             <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>
     <bean id="personService" class="river.amit.com.service.PersonService"></bean>
      <bean id="personDao" class="river.amit.com.dao.PersonDao">    
             <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller

```
package river.amit.com;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import river.amit.com.curd.Person;
import river.amit.com.dao.PersonDao;
import river.amit.com.dao.RoleDao;
import river.amit.com.service.PersonService;
import river.amit.com.service.RoleService;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class PersonController extends SimpleFormController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    PersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    RoleDao roleDao;

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    public PersonController() {
        setCommandClass(Person.class);
        setCommandName("personForm");
    }


    protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        Map referenceData = new HashMap();
        return referenceData;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws Exception {

        Person cust = new Person();
        // Make "Spring MVC" as default checked value
        cust.setFirstName("java");
        return cust;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(/*HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,*/ Object command/*, BindException errors*/)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub=
        Person cust=(Person) command;
        System.out.println("fgng");
            return new ModelAndView("message");
        }
        // return null;

}
```

jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form  commandName="personForm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstName">  <br> <br> 
<form:input path="firstName"/> 
  <input type="text" name="contact"> <br><br> 
 <!--  <input type="text" name="email"><br> <br>
  <input type="text" name="address"><br><br> 
  <input type="text" name="login"><br><br> --> 
  <form:button name="submit" value="submit"></form:button>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form:form>
  <a href="role.html">Role</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line from your spring configuration file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="river.amit.com"/>
```

or exclude `controller` package from scanning.